# Why is Dart BigInt overflowing?

Tags: dart, integer-overflow, bigint

It clearly says in the [docs](https://dart.dev/articles/archive/numeric-computation) that

> The third integer representation, bigint, holds an arbitrarily large signed integer.

Yes, if I do

`BigInt.parse('1401361620244348303075010764053798750806699051384896657186984262080729392169468490123546840166223286924678557627464612464171446377618435568706501027067406794991226499183297227160622976110894228304766631654633074535516079503916674556805715032127374387087475009709090')`

then that does work.

But when I create a `BigInt.from(0)` and repeatedly add something to it in order to convert this base64-encoded number

```
EwnG/GyyyZR6cgLrLuY+cvvRMlNqIr0GgyqWYmrpvsWwNbVcRQ7FWJFuGWFON81W7FbX0wMyjRV7WsMmk0zisj2baRl3v3Y1LPA8ncXU9vVfqCyeXVmUgv1T9wi1k41Zjr6h7WTjZJvyQC4YpaYpZdOJcuYm8yVOlfUKJ10lm2p9yxPJLtStvwJFZy4uCF2p/sfDATIv9Vyny3Ewx/B85Ae+eg2nlRcDmZdu5ByoqOfEYaU6H1fzzHvUSUBZvHv9zBLQ6PrLG6DhYhXzxol3zpbV02NGq3WfeBLhfl4DOUiVEDi0HSLw3xyJU+rw8rS1hoQeYcyogZ8p0I3BiNRs1Q==`,
```

to a BigInt, it overflows pretty quickly:

```
...
543848068542839930
1120308820846263418
3426151830059957370
-5797220206794818438
-5797220206794818438
-5797220206794818438
...
```

and get's stuck at `-5797220206794818438`. Why is that and how do I convert a base64 encoded number to BigInt then? I'm so confused.

Here's the code to convert base64 to BigInt:

```
/// Bytes are assumed to be BigEndian.
BigInt bytesToBigInt(List<int> bytes) {
  BigInt result = BigInt.from(0);
  int e = 0;
  for (int i in bytes.reversed) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
      int include = i & 1;
      i = i >> 1;
      e++;
      if (include == 1) {
        final val = pow(2, e);
        result += BigInt.from(include * val);
        print(' $result');
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Won't `pow(2, e)` eventually overflow?  You probably should be using [`BigInt.pow`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/BigInt/pow.html).  Also, if you're processing a list of bytes, then you could be shifting and accumulating 8 bits at a time instead of processing each bit individually.  Furthermore, [`BigInt` supports bitwise operators](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/BigInt/operator_bitwise_or.html).

Comment: If you want to avoid overflow, you need to avoid overflow... in all intermediate calculations. Just having a non-overflowing result is not sufficient, if you do stuff that can overflow along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific problem is caused by using `pow(2, e)` (which easily overflows once `e` gets large) instead of `BigInt.pow(2, e)`.

Also, your `bytesToBigInt` implementation seems more complicated than necessary.  As I noted in a comment, if you're processing a list of bytes, processing each bit is wasteful, and `BigInt` directly supports bitwise operators, so it creating a `BigInt` from a sequence of bytes could be simply:

```dart
/// Creates a [BigInt] from a sequence of [bytes], which is assumed to be in
/// big-endian order.
BigInt bytesToBigInt(Iterable<int> bytes) {
  BigInt result = BigInt.zero;
  for (int byte in bytes) {
    result = (result << 8) | BigInt.from(byte);
  }
  return result;
}
```

or:

```dart
BigInt bytesToBigInt(Iterable<int> bytes) => bytes.fold(
      BigInt.zero,
      (resultSoFar, byte) => (resultSoFar << 8) | BigInt.from(byte),
    );
```